# Closing vs Flagging

Tags: discussion, flagging, vote-to-close, votes

I've noticed when you vote to close a question you do not get a "Useful flags" count, however when you flag with reason "should be closed" then it classes as a close vote but you still get the useful flag point.

Is there any reason for this and what's the actual difference between the two when you already have close vote privileges?

Comment: at rep 3K+ [close flags are automatically converted to votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215970/165773)

Comment: @gnat So how do I get helpful flag points to get the badge?

Comment: it generally depends on the site, eg here at Workplace you probably can try flagging chatty comments